# Azure subdomain azurewebsites

Tags: azure

I have problems setting Azure :( Currently I use Azure websites
Achievement set my primary domain (mysite.com) but I can not run my subdomio.

How should I do it? Currently I have this:

```
A (Host)    
@ 255555555555
(Fake IP).
and
CNAME (Alias)
awverify awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net
www www-mysite.azurewebsites.net
```

I want to create a subdomain with the name "accounts" example: accounts.mysite.com

PS: Sorry, my native language is Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Create the sub domain (CNAME) in your registrar's DNS control panel. It should look like:

accounts => accounts-mysite.azurewebsites.net (where accounts-mysite.azurewebsites.net is your actual site name in Azure)

Then create the custom domain in Azure. CNAMES no longer have a need for all the awverify subdomains.

[Azure Custom Domain Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... Achievement create the domain but I can not point to a folder.
Example:

mysite.com/test/index.php to test.mysite.com